# Query to get SQL Server Compatibily Level

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

A 2016 Express SQL Server (compatibility level should be 130) shows compatibility level 100.

This is the query I am using to retrieve the current level, and it returns 100:

```
select cmptlevel from sysdatabases where name = db_name()
```

To be clear: I am trying to retrieve the *SERVER* compatibility level, and *not* a specific database.

If there is a way of getting it from the registry, then I can work with that too.

Comment: The **server** doesn't have a compatibility level - that's a property of an indvidual **database** ....

Comment: Servers don't have a compatibility level, it's just a database setting: [View or Change the Compatibility Level of a Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15). Servers have versions, and in your case that's 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, @marc_s and @Larnu! You have put me on the right path!

So basically, in order to check if a certain DB on an SQL Server has a compatibility level that is the same as the current server version, I need to convert the server's major version to the correct compatibility level, and then compare it.

This following query should convert it nicely, and return a single value that I can later on compare:

```
select
'ServerCompatibility' = 
    CASE CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion')  AS DECIMAL)
        WHEN 6.5  THEN '65' 
        WHEN 7  THEN '70'
        WHEN 8  THEN '80'
        WHEN 9  THEN '90'
        WHEN 10 THEN '100'
        WHEN 10.5 THEN '100'
        WHEN 11 THEN '11'
        WHEN 12 THEN '120'
        WHEN 13 THEN '130'
        WHEN 14 THEN '140'
        WHEN 15 THEN '150'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END
```

Comment: The `ProductMajorVersion` property doesn't exist in SQL Server 2008 R2 and earlier. Also `SERVERPROPERTY` was introduced in SQL 2000, IIRC. For supported SQL versions, You can use `SELECT PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS varchar(20)),4) * 10 AS HighestCompatibilityLevel;`

Comment: Thank you, @DanGuzman. However, you also have SQL version 2008/R2 that has a product version of 10.5 while the compatibility level should be 100. Still, since I do not foresee running this script of these versions, I will use your (much more elegant) query :-)

Comment: The `PARSENAME` function will return 10 for both SQL 2008 and SQL 2008 R2 so, even of you have those unsupported versions, it will still compute the correct compatibility level level.